# Laravel eloquent for non-related tables

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have tables as seen here[image]
An Athlete has many test days (e.g. one for each year), an Institution has teams e.g. Redham High School Rugby U14 Level. The team table is composed of the Institution, a sport and a level. Sport and Level are maintained in Codelist, which is just a table to maintain entities that are not big enough to be a table. Almost like replacing the hard coding of droplists.

Question 1: I don't see that the Codelist is related to the Team table, since Code list store unrelated info as well, like Country names, province names etc. Example of Codelist data below. Should they be related?

[image]

Question 2:
When creating a Test day record, I need the user to select for which team this athlete is getting tested for. I'm getting the Team records, but how do I now access the sport and level names from the Codelist? 
I can't do $team->sport->name as they're not related tables. 
Below is my current code. How do I get user friendly values for sportcode and levelcode e.g. Rugby U14.

```
            $teams = Team::whereHas('Institution', function($query){
                        $query->whereClient_id(1);
                    })->get();
```

I can with $teams loop get the sportcode and level code and now write separate queries to fetch the names from the codelist. This would send 3 collections back to the view and doesn't seem the eloquent way. Advice appreciated.

Comment: You could split the `Codelist` table into `SportCodes`, `LevelCodes`, `CountryCodes` etc., and refer it in appropriate tables using `id`.

Comment: So 6+ extra tables each with 1 attribute (name). Is that not bad design?